# .click event does not work in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have following script in my page :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.RemoveLink').click(function () {

        //dialog box
        $('#dialog').dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 400,
            modal: true,
            resizable: false
        });

        //end dialog box


        var fileAddress = this.id;
        var parent=$(this).parent().parent();
         $('#dialog').dialog('open');

        $('#dialog').dialog({ /*Initialising a confirmation dialog box (with  cancel/OK button)*/
            buttons: {
                "delete": function () {
                    $(this).dialog('close');

                    $.ajax({

                        url: "url",
                        data: { id: fileAddress },
                        success: function (mydata) {
                        parent.hide();
                            //$('#FileThumbs .ImageFileItem[id=' + fileAddress + ']').hide();
                        },
                        type: "GET"
                    });
                },
                "cancle": function () { //if the User Clicks the button "cancel"
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }
            }
        })
        return false;
    });
     $('.ResponseLink').click(function () {
        var idval = this.id;
        $.ajax({
            url: "url",
            data: { id: idval },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (mydata) {
                $("#ContactArea").empty().append(mydata);
            },
            type: "GET"
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

as you can see I also use jquery ui dial box. when I click a link with 'RemoveLink' class it works properly and dialog pops-up, but after I click on a link with 'ResponseLink' class and then click on a link with 'RemoveLink', the page does not show dialog and link works as a normal link.

Would you please help me ?

**Updated** : I Am using asp.net mvc , and its partial views. I put some form in a partial view and used Ajax.BeignForm() method for form to send it asynchronously, but there is a point. To make validation work with Ajax.BeignForm() I should reference necessary scripts, even though I have referenced theme in a view that calls partial view. I removed those re-referenced scripts and now dialog appears again, but I lost client side validation on form!!!!!

Comment: @ I cant understand what you mean ?

Comment: Do you re-append HTML with a RemoveLink class in the ResponeLink response?

Comment: There is a typo in your UI dialog, it says cancle instead of Cancel, but that's not the question here ;)

Comment: no I dont re-append a RemoveLink class in ResponeLink. triggering causes #ContactArea begin updated and RemoveLink is in a table separated from #ContactArea

Comment: Just for testing, what happen if you replace `$('.RemoveLink').click(` with `$('.RemoveLink').live('click'`?

Comment: still throws '$("#dialog").dialog is not a function ' error, when I explore firebug console.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of `.click`

```
$('#ContactArea').delegate('.RemoveLink', 'click', function (e) {...
```

In your case, you are attaching the `click` event to the `.RemoveLink` elements that were present at the time of attaching the click event handlers. Once you empty and clear out, those are replaced by new set of elements which don't have the event handler attached.

Using `.delegate` will make sure that however the content inside `#ContactsArea` changes, the `.RemoveLink` elements inside it will continue to be handled. Read more up on it in the docs.

Comment: But .RemoveLink is not inside of #ContactsArea.

Comment: Then probably something else is clearing them out. Or perhaps, do you see any error in the dev-tools/firebug console?

Comment: yes after triggering ResponeLink and then again clicking on RemoveLink, firebug shows an error but it disappears immediately- I made a brake point and saw that before reaching '$('#dialog').dialog({ ....' it throws an error but still cant see it.

Comment: You can't see it because the page is getting reloaded. Click the **Persist** button in firebug console. You should be able to see the error.

Comment: it gives me this : $("#dialog").dialog is not a function
[Break On This Error] $('#dialog').dialog('open');

Comment: @persian , that means your plugin for dialog didn't get installed properly

Comment: but I use it in other pages. Even it works on this page but after triggering RemoveLink it does not work, and requires to reload page

Comment: Do you have any js embedded in that html you are getting? Does it contain nasty stuff like `$.fn.dialog = undefined` or something like that? I know this is a long shot, but I am running out of ideas here :)

Comment: there is only one function which has been placed in master page (the page i talked so far embedded in master page) and here its defintion :   <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleUpdateContactForm(context) {
            //$('tr[id='context.CommentID;']').
            $("#ContactArea").empty().append(context);
            $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form');
        }
    </script>