# Ajax.BeignForm() and re-referencing necessary scripts?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, client-side-validation

I created a partial view which consist of an Ajax.BeignForm(), as far as I read about it, to make client side validation work, I should reference these scripts :

```
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="<%: Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Even though I already referenced them in view which calls the partial view (the one which consist Ajax.BeignForm()), I should re-reference them. But It made a problem which take two days of me, and cause the problem I described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7215750/click-event-does-not-work-in-jquery), and that problem only solves by removing above scripts, And removing them causes the client side validation not to work. 
Do you have Any Idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget these guys:

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Then everything set up correctly. How do you check that validation doesn't work?
Check js errors and markup in browser.

Comment: I leave some required field empty.

Comment: just in case, maybe you forget Html.ValidationSummary or Html.ValidationMessageFor controls. Does server side validation works?

Comment: I made a break point in [HttpPost] action, but it seems that form is not begin sent there, even using  'Html.ValidationSummary(false) ' does not show any errors.

Comment: So you doesn't reach your action on post, am i right? Check js errors on page. Can you please post a piece of markup from browser here with on of required fields.

Comment: @persianDev let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2962/discussion-between-dima-and-persian-dev)

Comment: @ Dima, adding $.validator.unobtrusive.parse('form'); worked for partial edit page ! thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add these 2 keys to your appSettings:

```
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

And no, if you have those scripts on the page already, you shouldn't have to add them again.

Comment: Yes I have them in my web config appSettings. Removing the scripts I mentioned in my question, causes the client side validation not to work.

Comment: When you remove the scripts, did you check the HTML on the client to make sure the scripts from the parent page are there?

Comment: Yes, because all views have a MasterPageFile file (except for partial views) which it-self contains necessary scripts. 'jquery-1.5.1.min.js' , 'jquery.validate.min.js', 'jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js', 'jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js'